# Linux: get Thread ID by handle from boost::thread

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, boost-thread

I'm using `boost::thread` (which is in a next step using `pthread`) but would like to get the thread id / (lightweight) pid by the `boost::thread` pointer. I manage to do this with windows by using the member `native_handle()` but I couldn't find an alternative with linux.

```
boost::thread * boost_thread ptr = new boost::thread(/*...*/);
ptr->native_handle();
```

I've found a lot of posts about the **current** thread using something like `pthread_self()` but I'm no trying to get the thread id from inside this thread, I want to get it from the outside for the thread I just created using `new boost::thread`. Is there a way to retrieve the thread id/pid by using the native handle or something from the boost::thread structure?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: **Not a duplicate** cause the other thread doesn't solve this... at least not when getting the `pthread_t` from a `boost::thread` and thus having no influence upon it's creation. Or solved in a way like: not possible.

Comment: `boost::thread::native_handle()` on linux returns the `pthread_t` for the thread. Thus, your question is actually a duplicate.

Comment: What are you needing the linux thread id for? You use boost::thread, so you aren't apparently implementing your own thread library, so why do you need to access kernel details?

Comment: So if I understand the other thread correctly it's not possible?

Comment: @user2079303: I want this for debugging purposes. I want to see the results in htop and compare to my logs while using linux the same way as currently in windows. But for that I need to compare my internal thread view with external ones (just like htop for example)

Comment: I check the definition of ``pthread_t`` and it seems it won't get me anywhere in the short run. These fields doesn't seem to have what I need:  ``void * handle; void *(*  func )(void *arg); void *  arg; void *  ret;``

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to call getpid() directly from the thread [getpid()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html).
(Please do not forget, that in Linux process and thread is almost the same, thus you need the process ID).

Comment: In multithreaded programs this is sadly not the same.

Comment: It's probably possible to extend ``boost::thread`` and wrap the calling convention to include ``getpid()`` just after creation for multiple platforms and provide it to the outside world

Answer (score 1):

On most unixoids `pid_t current_thread_id = gettid();` will return the current thread id, but glibc does not provide this function. Instead you have to call:

```
pid_t current_thread_id = (pid_t) syscall(__NR_gettid);
```

Getting the id from outside that thread will become difficult. Using the native handle of pthread is an unsupported way of getting thread ids. Using `boost::thread::get_id()` will return an object, so it is not lightweight.

Comment: Thanks... I didn't want to try to access private object data, but the private implementation details of ``boost::thread::id`` do include the id... at least in windows.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux I am able to get thread id using boost::this_thread::get_id()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>


void func(){

  std::cout<<"Thrd Id "<<boost::this_thread::get_id()<<" "<<std::endl;
}


int main(){

  boost::thread thd1(&func);

  std::cout<<std::endl;
  boost::thread thd2(&func);

  while(1){}

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Thrd Id 7f8ddcef8700
Thrd Id 7f8dd44f7700
```

Comment: This is not the id of the thread, which is a positive number of a 16bit integer.

Comment: looking good but the id sadly doesn't correlate with the one from the process monitor